# how can i update the date of columns when the data is received by one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a bit new to sql and couldn't get this.
how can i update the date of column when the data is received by one column and that matches a certain value then the date should be automatically updated in a column

Here is my table how it looks like

```
Id level level_4_Updated level_5_updated level_6_updated
1....4.............Null........................Null.......................Null
2....5.............Null........................Null.......................Null
3....6.............Null........................Null.......................Null
4....5.............Null........................Null.......................Null
5....4.............Null........................Null.......................Null
```

if the actual_level is 4 then the date should be updated in the level_4_updated and if level is 5 then the date should be updated in level_5_updated automatically when the level get the data. and the update of each row should be independent. if we update any row it should not effect the other rows. Can i get the query for this with out using triggers.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
update t
    set level_4_Updated = (case when level = 4 then now() else level_4_Updated end),
        level_5_Updated = (case when level = 5 then now() else level_5_Updated end),
        level_6_Updated = (case when level = 6 then now() else level_6_Updated end)
    where id = @id;
```

Comment: level_4_Updated, level_5_Updated, level_6_Updated are datetime format so they wont allow integer to get inserted.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: @EshwarChinta . . . And where is an integer being put into that column?

Comment: sorry for that @gordon, but the syntax is not accepting. can I get another query

Comment: @EshwarChinta . . . What error are you getting?  The syntax looks fine.

Comment: How can i declare @id in the above query

Comment: @EshwarChinta . . . Your question says:  "that matches a certain value".  That is the value that needs to be matched.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think that English is not your first language !

When you say "date", I think that you mean data or data entry.

So what you are trying to do is apply a data entry into a column called "updated-level_i" where the column called "level" holds the value i.

You simply write a [stored procedure](http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/definition/stored-procedure) to go through each row of data in your table, get the data-entry in the "level" column, assign an appropriate update column based on this value and then execute an update on this column.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i need to get the DATE, when the column name called 'level' gets updated, then I need to update the date of that row with respect the value of the 'Level'